# How can I create a list of object based on checkboxfor created for the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I have this view based on a list of a model where I create strongly-typed checkboxes for each items of the model based on a boolean.

Here's my view:

```
@using MyApp.Models
@model IList<MyApp.Models.ObjInfo>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Obj Inventory";
}

<h2>Search Inventory</h2>

<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        (Many search filters which are non-relevant)
        <p>
            Send Items: @Html.ActionLink("Click Here", "SendItems")
        </p>
    }
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Obj Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Number In Stock
        </th>
        (...)
        <th>
            Select Item
        </th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OtherObj.m_Name)
        </td>
        (...)
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.m_IsSelected)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

The whole process works fine and I can actually generate a view with checkboxes for each item of my list of model.

Now my question is that I want to create a list which would regroup only the items in the list which are checked and send them to the controller. How could I do that? Can anyone help me or suggest me a way to work?

Thank you!

*** EDIT ***

Here is the HttpPost Method used to get the List of items as mentioned below:

```
//
        // GET: /Inventory/SendItems
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SendItems(IList<ObjInfo> listToSend)
        {
            m_ListObjToSend = new List<ObjInfo>();

            foreach (var item in listToSend.Where(item => item.m_IsSelected))
            {
                m_ListObjToSend .Add(item);
            }

            return View(m_ListObjToSend );
        }
```

However I have encountered many problems:

- This method does NOT work if I put the [HttpPost] attribute (it will show as "Not Found");

  - The list I am supposed to receive is null;
  - Each hiddenfield linked with the checkbox has default value as false even if the checked value shows true;
  - I am using an actionlink because I do not want to use a button, there is already one that is doing another job.

I am open for any comments / help available, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the CheckBoxFor helper to generate checkboxes you will notice that it generates an additional hidden field along with each checkbox. This means that all values will be sent to the controller and you will have to filter in your controller those that are checked.

Also I would recommend you using indexes to ensure proper model binding. You just need to use an `IList<ObjInfo>` or `ObjInfo[]` which is trivially easy achievable by calling `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` extension methods on your view model before passing it to the view:

```
@using MyApp.Models
@model IList<ObjInfo>
...
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) 
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].OtherObj.m_Name)
        </td>
        (...)
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[i].m_IsSelected)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
...
```

And now your controller action could directly take the list of items:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(IEnumerable<ObjInfo> model)
{
    ...
}
```

and if you wanted to find the selected values, you could simply get them through LINQ:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(IEnumerable<ObjInfo> model)
{
    var selectedItems = model.Where(x => x.m_IsSelected);
    ...
}
```

Remark: `m_Name` and `m_IsSelected` is a **disastrously bad** naming convention for a properties in C#.

---

UPDATE:

Another issue you have with your code is that your `Html.BeginForm` doesn't contain any input field. It has only a single ActionLink which obviously only does a GET request. If you want to submit the values you should wrap your entire table with the form and use a submit button and not some action links:

```
@using MyApp.Models
@model IList<ObjInfo>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Obj Inventory";
}

<h2>Search Inventory</h2>

<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SendItems", null, FormMethod.Post))
    {
        (Many search filters which are non-relevant)

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Obj Name</th>
                <th>Number In Stock</th>
                (...)
                <th>Select Item</th>
           </tr>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) 
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!-- 
                    This will not be sent to your controller because it's only a label.
                    You will need a corresponding hidden field if you want to get that value back
                    -->
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].OtherObj.m_Name)
                </td>
                (...)
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[i].m_IsSelected)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </table>

        <p>
            Send Items: <button type="submit">Click Here</button>
        </p>
    }
</p>
```

So really, 2 things you should learn:

1. The [`naming convention`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) that the default model binder expects when binding to a list
2. How to use a javascript debugging tool (such as FireBug and/or Chrome Developper Toolbar) which will allow you to inspect all the values that are sent to your server and immediately recognized whether you respected the convention you learned in 1.

Comment: Ok, I will try this out. Thank you very much! Just a question: you seem to favour using a "for" instead of a foreach, why?

Comment: Read this article to understand the proper naming convention that you should use when binding to a list: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx Once you understand this you will also understand why I use `for` instead of `foreach`.

Comment: On my way! Thank you for your support, not the first time you help me out! :)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I have tried everything you mentioned but when I debug the code, when the HTTPPost method is called (see edited code up there), the list is null... why?

Comment: And I've just seen that each hiddenfield value is false... Then again, did I forgot to do something, or will the value be set when I click on the actionlink?

Comment: Yes, I have noticed another two serious issues with your code. The checkboxes are not inside your form and your form doesn't even have a submit button. A form without a submit button doesn't send anything to the server (that's basic HTML that you should learn before getting into ASP.NET MVC). You have used some ActionLink but this generates an anchor and an anchor sends a GET request and none of your input fields ever reaches the server. The second issue is that you should wrap put all your input fields (such as checboxes and textboxes) inside the form. I have updated my answer with a sample.